# Llenar tabla en nodejs (jade) de una consulta sql

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Tengo esta consulta

```
getAnalisisDetallado: function(req, res, next) {

        var config = require('.././database/config');
        // connect to your database
        sql.connect(config, function(err) {

            if (err) console.log(err);

            // create Request object
            var request = new sql.Request();

            // query to the database and get the records
            request.query('SELECT SI_Articulo, SI_UM, SI_Ubicacion FROM SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD', function(err, rows, recordset) {

                if (err) console.log(err)

                // send records as a response
                res.send(recordset);
            return res.render('menu/analisisDetallado', { title: 'Users', rows: rows });
            sql.close();
            });
        });


    }
```

La cual me trae unos datos de la base de datos y lo que debo hacer es insertarla en una tabla

```
div(class="container aDetallado")
    div(class="row center span10")
      table(id="test-table" class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed")
        thead
          tr
            th Articulo
              i(class="icon-filter editable editable-click editable-empty")
            th Um
              i(class="icon-filter editable editable-click editable-empty")
            th #Ubic
              i(class="icon-filter editable editable-click editable-empty")
        tbody
           each item in rows
            tr
              td= item.SI_Articulo
              td= item.SI_UM
              td= item.SI_Ubicacion
```

y me sale el siguiente error `Error Can´t set headers after they are sent`
No se por que sera ese error de headers.

Comment: Probablemente es porque mandas la información y luego intentas renderizar la vista.

Comment: ¿Resolviste tu problema anterior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo que hago normalmente es renderizar la vista y le paso los parámetros de la siguiente manera:

```
res.render('carpeta/vista', {
           title: 'Titulo de la vista',
           data: JSON.parse(rows)
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

Estás enviando **dos respuestas** para una sola petición:

> Error Can´t set headers **after they are send**

Dado que haces esto:

```
res.send(recordset); // ¿para qué es esto?
return res.render('menu/analisisDetallado', { title: 'Users', rows: rows });
```

Tanto `res.send` como `res.render` son respuestas HTTP que estás enviando para una sola petición. No tiene sentido usar ambas; o envías los datos como `json` o renderizas una vista con los datos.